# Error Message .Path line 0 position

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My local and production server works well. It just that i get the below error message after i deployed to my testing server.

[image]

Comment: Could you please locate the line or block of code that causing the error and include them with the post?

Comment: Already solved the issue due to application pool and setup pool configured wrongly

Comment: Then its better to remove the question or you can write your own answer